# Does Java StringBuilder setLength method redundantly assign \0 to its char[] value array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringbuilder

I'm stuyding the Java StringBuilder's [setLength method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.setLength%28int%29).

If the new length is larger, it sets the newly "appended" array indices to '\0':

```
public void setLength(int newLength) {
     if (newLength < 0)
         throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(newLength);
     if (newLength > value.length)
         expandCapacity(newLength);

     if (count < newLength) {
         for (; count < newLength; count++)
             value[count] = '\0';
     } else {
         count = newLength;
     }
 }
```

Is this unnecessary? In expandCapacity(newLength) the Arrays.copyOf method is used to create a new char[] array with size newLength:

```
public static char[] copyOf(char[] original, int newLength) {
    char[] copy = new char[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

The [Java language specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) that components in arrays are initialized to their default values. For char, this is '\u0000' which I understand to be the unicode equivalent of '\0'.

Additionally, the [StringBuilder setLength documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength(int)) states:

> If the newLength argument is greater than or equal to the current
>   length, sufficient null characters ('\u0000') are appended so that
>   length becomes the newLength argument.

But the length of this array can be accessed directly without assigning values to its components:

```
char[] array = new char[10];
System.out.println(array.length); // prints "10"
```

So, is the for-loop in setLength redundant?

Comment: the for loop is to append the \0s.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi The documentation the OP cites from the JLS suggests this appending is unnecessary, since `\0` is the default value for `char`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **necessary** when we want to reuse `StringBuilder`.

Assume we remove this code in `StringBuilder`

```
  if (count < newLength) {
         for (; count < newLength; count++)
             value[count] = '\0';
     }
```

And we test with below code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("test");
builder.setLength(0); //the `value` still keeps "test", `count` is 0
System.out.println(builder.toString()); //print empty
builder.setLength(50); //side effect will happen here, "test" is not removed because expandCapacity still keeps the original value
System.out.println(builder.toString());  // will print test
```

The code your mention is in jdk6, in java8 is different.